# Cómo hacer esto en Linq "select * from Personas where PersonaId IN (1000000006, 1000000024)"

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]**¿Cómo podría hacer esto usuado LinQ?**

```sql
select * from Personas where PersonaId IN (1000000006, 1000000024)
```

Comment: Por favor compártenos lo que has intentado en tu código C#.  Y explícanos cual es la parte que no tienes claro. ¿Es la duda con el `IN` por ejemplo?

Comment: guiate de la sig. URL, segun veo manejan la inquietud que manifiestas. Saludos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959752/where-in-clause-in-linq

Comment: Hola Hector, gracias por la edición. Por favor incluye el código en texto formateado en vez de una imagen, porque no podemos copiar y probar una imagen. Adicionalmente, noto que `personasIds` es una cadena.  ¿Puedes aclarar su contenido por favor? Lo normal sería que recibieras uan lista de ids o algo por el estilo, no una cadena.

Comment: Si, personasIds es un string con como esto: (1000000006, 1000000024) y lo que debere recibir es una lista de personas que tienen como su identificador esos Ids.

Comment: No sería posible recibir mas bien un `List<int> personasIds` como parametro?  Al recibir una cadena, estaría obligado a separar los valores antes de poder hacer la consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque no lo dices explícitamente, es lógico que `PersonaId` sea de tipo numérico. En ese caso, necesitas recibir o crear una lista numérica de ids de personas.

En tu caso, dices que recibes los valores en el formato `(1000000006, 1000000024)` en el parámetro `string personasIds`. Sería mucho mejor si cambiaras el parámetro para recibir una lista de `int` de una vez, para evitarte hacer parsing innecesario de las comas y paréntesis, y tener luego que convertir el `string` a `int`.

Con esto en su lugar, entonces puedes usar `.Contains` para generar un `IN` en SQL:

```
public static List<Personas> GetPersonasByIds(IEnumerable<int> personasIds)
{
    using(var dbContext = new GV_ATIMAEntities())
    {
        return dbContext.Personas.Where(p => personasIds.Contains(p.PersonaId)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Nota que uso `IEnumerable<int>` para el tipo del parámetro, pero pudieras usar otros tipos como `List<int>` o `int[]`. De hecho, hasta pudieras usar un `params int[]` si quieres poder llamar el método de esta forma:

```
var listaPersonas = GetPersonasByIds(1000000006, 1000000024);
```

Comment: Si especifica que PersonaId es un string, "Si, personasIds es un string con como esto: (1000000006, 1000000024) y lo que debere recibir es una lista de personas que tienen como su identificador esos Ids"

Comment: @Luis: El parámetro con la lista de personaIds en conjunto es un string, pero la columna parece ser numérica. De lo contrario, su parámetro sería `('1000000006', '1000000024')` con las comillas.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas convertir la cadena que recibes en cadenas separadas, suponiendo que la cadena que recibes está separada por comas:

```
string[] ids = personasIds.Split(',');

using (var context = new GV_ATIMAEntities())
{
    var personas = context.Personas
        .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.PersonaId))
        .ToList();
}
```

EDIT: Si el campo "PersonaId" es numérico, debes convertir los datos en enteros:

```
string[] idsStr = personasIds.Split(',');
var ids = new List<int>();

foreach(var idStr in idsStr)
{
    var id = 0;
    if (Int32.TryParse(idStr, out id)
    {
        ids.Add(id);
    } 
}

using (var context = new GV_ATIMAEntities())
{
    var personas = context.Personas
        .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.PersonaId))
        .ToList();
}
```

Si el campo no es entero sino long, debes cambiar esta línea:

```
var ids = new List<long>();
```

y esta:

```
long id;
if (Int64.TryParse(idStr, out id)
```

Aunque en ese caso lo mejor sería pasar una lista de números y no una cadena.